# Java Web Service returns string with &gt; and &lt; instead of > and <

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I have a java web service that returns a string. I'm creating the body of this xml string with a `DocumentBuilder` and `Document` class. When I view source of the returned XML (Which looks fine in the browser window) instead of <> it's returning `&lt;` and `&gt;` around the XML nodes.

Please help.

******UPDATE (including code example)**
The code is not including any error catching, it was stripped for simplicity.
One code block and three methods are included:
The first code block (EXAMPLE SETUP) shows the basics of what the Document object is setup to be like. the method `appendPayment(...)` is where the actual document building happens. It calls on two helper methods `getTagValue(...)` and `prepareElement(...)`
**Note, this code is meant to copy specific parts from a pre-existing xml string, `xmlString`, and grap the necessary information to be returned later.

******UPDATE 2**
Response added at the end of the question

************** Follow-up question to the first answer is here:**
[How to return arbitrary XML Document using an Eclipse/AXIS2 POJO Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877515/how-to-return-arbitrary-xml-document-using-an-eclipse-axis2-pojo-service)

```
EXAMPLE SETUP
{
    //create new document
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder newDocBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document newDoc = newDocBuilder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = newDoc.createElement("AllTransactions");

    newDoc.appendChild(rootElement);
    appendPayment(stringXML, newDoc);
}

public static void appendPayment(String xmlString, Document newDoc) throws Exception
{
    //convert string to inputstream
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes());
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document oldDoc =   docBuilder.parse(bais);
    oldDoc.getDocumentElement().normalize();            

    NodeList nList = oldDoc.getChildNodes();
    Node nNode = nList.item(0);
    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

    //Create new child node for this payment
    Element transaction = newDoc.createElement("Transaction");
    newDoc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(transaction);


    //status
    transaction.appendChild(prepareElement("status", eElement, newDoc));

    //amount
    transaction.appendChild(prepareElement("amount", eElement, newDoc));
}

private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement)
{
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();
    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
    return nValue.getNodeValue();
}

private static Element prepareElement(String sTag, Element eElement, Document newDoc)
{
    String str = getTagValue(sTag, eElement);
    Element newElement = newDoc.createElement(sTag);
    newElement.appendChild(newDoc.createTextNode(str));
    return newElement;
}
```

Finally, I use the following method to convert the final `Document` object to a `String`

```
public static String getStringFromDocument(Document doc)
{
    try
    {
       DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
       StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
       StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
       TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
       Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
       transformer.transform(domSource, result);
       return writer.toString();
    }
    catch(TransformerException ex)
    {
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}
```

The header type of the response is as follows

```
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

This is an example response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <getTransactionsResponse xmlns="http://services.paypal.com">
        <getTransactionsReturn>&lt;AllTransactions&gt;&lt;Transaction&gt;&lt;status&gt;PENDING&lt;/status&gt;&lt;amount&gt;55.55&lt;/amount&gt;&lt;/transaction&gt;
        </getTransactionsResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please describe the specific Java web service technology you are using (e.g. plain-old-Servlet, Spring, JAX-WS, Axis2, CXF, Grails, Play!, etc.); this will give others some context by which to understand your issue.

Comment: @Sababado: **how exactly** do you build the return value? Because it sounds like you build the XML string yourself and set some value of your return bean to that (which would result in exactly the escaping you describe).

Comment: I've updated the question, it now shows the code I'm using.

Comment: Ok, please also describe how specifically you are using Axis2 for this service (e.g. POJO, AXIOM, wsdl2java ADB/XMLBeans/JiBX).  It looks like you're building the XML document fine but it's something to do with your usage of Axis2 that makes the framework think it should escape the entities rather than pass the document through directly.

Comment: To deploy the web service, I have a dynamic web project with a class that defines the interface of my service.  The method I am concerned with returns a String type.  To create and deploy the web service I right click on the class (contained in the dynamic web project) and select create web service, here I indicate that I want a "Bottom up Java bean Web Service" and that the service implementation comes from the class in my dynamic web project.  This starts my service and creates a WSDL that has the definition of my ports and endpoints.

Comment: Is this Eclipse?  NetBeans?  Some other IDE?  Please update your question describing all of this information, it is highly relevant to your problem (arguably even more so than the code itself).  Just guessing here, but at the most general level, it sounds like it could be something like the response "Content-Type" header having a value "text/html" instead of "text/xml"...

Comment: The IDE is Eclipse. I'm checking up on the Content-Type now....

Comment: An example resposne and Header have been added to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The framework is doing what you tell it; your method returns a `String` which means the generated WSDL should have a response message of type [`<xsd:string>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#string).  As we know, XML strings must encode certain characters as [character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference) (i.e. "`<`" becomes "`&lt;`" so the XML parser treats it as a string, not the beginning of an XML element as you intend).  If you want to return an XML document then you must define the XML structure in the [WSDL `<types>` section](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_types) and set the response message part to the appropriate element.

To put it another way, you are trying to send "typed" data without using the strong type system provided by SOAP/WSDL (namely XML schema); this is generally regarded as bad design (see [*Loosely typed versus strongly typed web services*](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-loosevstrong/index.html)).

The ultimate solution is to to define the response document via a proper [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/).  If there is no set schema, as by the design of your service, then use the [`<xsd:any>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#declare-openness) type for the message response type, although this approach [has its pitfalls](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/ws-tip-xsdcaution/index.html).  Moreover, such a redesign implies a schema-first (top-down) development model and from the comment stream it seems that you are currently practicing code-first (bottom-up) approach.  Perhaps your tools provide a mechanism such as a "general XML document" return type or annotation which achieves the same effect.

Comment: The types section of the wsdl are automatically generated based on the code that will become the service.  The function of intrest has an org.w3c.DOM.Document that holds the XML that I want to return.  This Document is converted to a string and returned, because the Document object is not serialized and does not have a public constructor.  Is there another type that I can use as the return type for my function that will hold the XML structure throught the service call?

Comment: @Sababado: I suggest you ask a new question like "How can I return an arbitrary XML document using an Eclipse/AXIS2 POJO Service?", this way, people familiar with those tools and that implementation strategy can give answers.  I have some experience with AXIS2 but always top-down (WSDL first).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. If you know of anyone who may be able to help with this step, please pass the link along
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877515/how-to-return-arbitrary-xml-document-using-an-eclipse-axis2-pojo-service