# Send XML to webservice

Tags: java, xml, string, web-services

I am send a XML String which is extract from XML file to a jax Web-services

My XML is

```
<GTSRequest command="version">
<Authorization account="jrl" user="" password="123456"/>
</GTSRequest>
```

and Java Code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String a = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/XML/Get Current GTS Version.xml";
    System.out.println(convertXMLFileToString(a));
    // call web service 
    System.out.println(gtsServiceRequest(convertXMLFileToString(a)));

}

public static String convertXMLFileToString(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String everything;
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        everything = sb.toString();
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
    return  everything;
}
```

But when string goes to server the string is change in

```
lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot; ?&gt;&#xD;
&lt;GTSRequest command=&quot;version&quot;&gt;&#xD;
&lt;Authorization account=&quot;jrl&quot; user=&quot;&quot; password=&quot;123456&quot;/&gt;&#xD;
&lt;/GTSRequest&gt
```

My string conver to HTML acsii value, so how can i stop this?

Comment: Please show us the code of `gtsServiceRequest()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849666/java-web-service-returns-string-with-gt-and-lt-instead-of-and) helpful, quoting from the link:

> "your method returns a String which means the generated WSDL should have a response message of type . As we know, XML strings must encode certain characters as character entity references (i.e. "<" becomes "& lt;" so the XML parser treats it as a string, not the beginning of an XML element as you intend). If you want to return an XML document then you must define the XML structure in the WSDL  section and set the response message part to the appropriate element."